# How to use image multiple times after once is requested :)

Tags: jquery

Hi I want to use same image multiple times responsed once, Am I need to request again for same image ?

This will create problems for bandwidth :

```
.c_description div {
    display:inline-block;
    width:25px;
    height:20px;
    margin-bottom:-2px; 
    background:url("../images/general/emoji.png") no-repeat;
    background-position:2px -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as your server doesn't do anything strange, and it returns the proper headers for caching the image, you can request it as many times as you want.

When the image is requested the first time, it will be downloaded and added to the browsers cache, after that, it will be loaded from cache, and not downloaded from the server again.

Comment: ty for answer, is there is any code for "cache iamge to browser =true " maybe ?

Comment: Most webservers will do this automatically for you, unless you turn it off. For an overview of the headers, see -> https://www.keycdn.com/blog/http-cache-headers/